# jqModal overlay in Firefox not transparent

Tags: jquery, jqmodal

I'm using jqModal for an application I'm developing.  It works great in IE8, but in Firefox 3.5.2, the window comes up but the overlay is solid black.  It seems like a CSS problem but I'm not sure.  The samples on the jqModal site work fine.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Site:  ASP.NET with MS AJAX

jQuery 1.3.2

latest jqModal

**UPDATE:** After rearranging my page and usercontrols so that ALL `<script>` and CSS references were in the hosting .aspx page (none whatsoever in the usercontrols), the problem magically went away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rearranging my page and usercontrols so that ALL  and CSS references were in the hosting .aspx page (none whatsoever in the usercontrols), the problem magically went away.

Answer (score 0):

How are you initializing it? If you specify the `overlay` parameter and is 100 then the overlay will be completely opaque. A code snippet, perhaps?

Comment: Wait, that makes no sense - it works in IE8! In that case, maybe some of your CSS is interfering with it. Have you tried looking at the styles applied in Firebug?

Comment: .. also compared the styles between the sample site and mine, the are identical.